# VB6 object variable not set

Tags: vb6, syntax-error

I have a report in VB6 that has been completed. There is no issues whatsoever when I try to run it once, however, if I try to run it again I get the annoying "91 Object variable or With block variable not set". I don't see what I'm doing wrong, i get this error when I go to SELECT stuff from SQL SERVER...please see code below

```
g_SQL = "select Rpt as Label, rptOrder from tblData " & _
        " where Rpt like '" & Client & "%' " 

g_RS.Open g_SQL, g_cnDat, adOpenStatic
```

SO i do this here, a simple SELECT QUERY, and like I said it goes fine. I pull this data, use it for my report, then I do this

```
g_RS.close
```

When I try to run the report the 2nd time, it stops on

```
g_RS.open g_SQL,g_cnDat, adopenStatic
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: try to destroy the variable after you close the connection, i am not sure, but it might be a memory issue, something like g_RS = nothing

Comment: I've tried this too. No idea why it's doing that. Very very annoying.

Comment: have you checked the db where you try to connect if they let you connect more than 1 time per second? try to put a timer in the application, and wait two minutes, and then it should execute again, see if its a db security issue.

Comment: Yea that's not an issue. Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming g_ indicates a global variable? Bad, bad practice for a RecordSet object. Localize the variable, and you'll likely find the issue.

Comment: yes all these application use globals for recordsets

Answer (score 0):

All set, it looks like i was opening it later on in the function and never closed it. Thanks for help!